# Plotting histogram for all features with titles

Tags: python, distribution, covariance, normal-distribution

I wrote the following code to plot histograms of all the features in my dataframe dff. My code snippet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dff.head()
for i in dff.columns:
        plt.figure()
        plt.hist(dff[i])
```

However the histograms just get plotted without the feature name / column name.Is there a way i could also print the column name below each of distribution charts so that i can relate which distribution corresponds to which column?

Comment: You can set a title `plt.title(i)`. But are you sure you want to plot each of these in a separate figure instead of using subplots?

Answer (score 3):

this is the first time I actually got chance to answer a question.

if you add this line it will print the column name as the title, you can add other text to it as well. This is a super useful little function

```
plt.title(f'{i}')
```

here is it in your code

```
dff.head()
for i in dff.columns:
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(f'{i}')
    plt.hist(dff[i])
```

*edited this as I put the title in the wrong place originally